# Link with QueryString

Tags: web-part, filter

I have a webpart page with a Query String Filter. That works fine, but I also need some links on the web part page that uses the querystring. Any ideas?

Update: Sorry for bad explanation. On the web part page (whice have querystring "kid") I want a menu with links. The links is to other web part pages and they need to have the current querystring ("kid") included. How can I insert the current kid-querystring to the links?

Comment: You might want to expand your question to say exactly what you're trying to achieve and what you've done so far to accomplish it.  I'd like to help, but don't know what you're after.

Comment: Have you setup the web part connection to consume the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass on the querystring you would need to do some custom formatting, perhaps with a client side script that can append the querystring to those menu link items.